# Decomposition of a group element as a product of a coset and subgroup element

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, matrix-equations

It is a known fact in the theory of non-linear symmetry realizations in physics that we can decompose a group element as (sum signs are implied)

$$
g=e^{\theta_\alpha X^\alpha}e^{u_i t^i}
$$
where $t^i$ are generators of a subgroup $H \subset G$, and $X^\alpha$ are an orthonormal basis completion of G which may be thought of 'generating' the left coset $G/H$.

I tried to convince myself that this can always be done inspecting

$$
e^{\beta_\alpha X^\alpha + v_i t^i}=e^{\theta_\alpha X^\alpha}e^{u_i t^i}.
$$

I proceed to use the BCH formula to obtain an equation very similar to (up to sign and other unimportant mistakes)

$$
\beta_\alpha X^\alpha + v_i t^i =\theta\cdot X + u\cdot t+ \frac{\theta^a u^b}{2} c_{abc}X^c + \frac{u^a u^b \theta^c}{12} c_{bcd} c_{ade}X^e + \frac{\theta^a \theta^b u^c}{12} c_{bcd} c_{ade}T^e +\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{u\theta}^4),
$$

where $\{T\}\equiv\{X,t\}$, and I have used that the $X$ furnish a representation of $\mathfrak{h}$: $[t^a,X^b]\sim X$.

Now, the equation above is polynomial in $\theta$ and $u$, so that we should be able to find a solution over $\mathbb{C}$ for every pair of vectors $(\beta,v)$. But is it right? If this is enough, then it seems that the fact that  $[t^a,X^b]\sim X$ wasn't needed.

And what about the fact that we have an infinite number of terms? Is this proposition supposed to be true only approximately (i.e., close enough to the identity)? And what if we want a solution with *real* $(\theta,u)$?

Comment: I'm not completely sure of your notation. Are $\theta$ and $u$ supposed to be numbers? If so, this is not known to be true. We would need the group to be connected for a start and even then I don't think it is proved that any Lie group element can be found as the product of exactly two exponentials although I don't think there are known counter examples. Forcing one of the two elements to always be in a fixed subgroup is even more restrictive.

Comment: Also that equation is not polynomial it is an infinite power series which does not terminate in general and so I do not think it has to have a solution even over the complex numbers. It could easily diverge.

Comment: @Callum would the proposition be true if we restricted ourselves to elements close enough to the identity? Sometimes this condition is specified in the physics literature and it seems to solve the issue of the polynomial equations being infinite-degree.

Comment: Yes that would probably make it work although I don't have a proof off the top of my head. In general, close to the identity any element can be written as a single exponential

Comment: For standard physics cases, $\beta (\theta , u)$ and $v(\theta, u)$ are routine functions, and can be inverted to $\theta (\beta, v)$ and $u(\beta, v)$. You may compute them explicitly, e.g., in the case of $SO(4)/SO(3)$, the celebrated σ-model. This is the $S^3\to S^2$ case, and there hardly are any pathologies... The point is you may represent the generators in terms of Pauli matrices, whose exponentials are trivial to evaluate explicitly.